# Use a image from url in a android wear notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I´m using notifications for the androidwear watch in my project.
My intentention is that the background of the notificatión will be an image extract from a url, but i don´t know how to do it.

The doc of the NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()explain:

```
.setBackground(bBitmap);
```

but.. if i want to load the backgroud from a url?

i´ll be reading about this, but without success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Volley (Highly efficient networking library) to download the image in URL and use it. You will get a bitmap response. There are various tutorials for Volley ImageRequest.

See this question [Import Android volley to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059576/import-android-volley-to-android-studio) to see how to add volley library to android-studio

Try this to learn to requst images from url using volley.

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

if u still cant't do it, i can help u with the code.
Happy coding :)