# Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.0.1

Tags: android-studio

I just added `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.1'` in the dependency list and got the exception. Am I missing anything?

**Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.0.1**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pankajgarg.practise"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.1'
}
```

I also tried with volley version 1.0.0 but same problem

**build.grade**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: although you tried 1.0.0, but can you please try compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0' ?

Comment: please use this: `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`
as shown in https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: please use version 1.1.0 for volley. It's posted to jcenter https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an internet connection and rebuild your project so that Android Studio can download the libraries

Answer (score 0):

According to repo `com.android.volley:volley:1.0.1` this version is not available. So you need to change from

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.1'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

You can check this repository link see to all available version of **Volley** [here](https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-utils/com/android/volley/volley/)

GitHub Repository [here](https://github.com/google/volley) and Developer documentation for more help [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Still getting problem ? please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059576/import-android-volley-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have tried all the possible solutions in the internet but still could not fix the issue...
What worked for me is to sync the gradle file first by removing the jcenter() from the buildscript repositories in build.gradle(Project) and then again syncing after putting jcenter() in the buildscript repositories in build.gradle(Project).