# Where will you add the volley Library in Android Studio project?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley, gradle-dependencies

I've added the below lines in the dependency.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'\
 implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

I recently started working on Android Studio and I want to use the Volley library for my app but I can't add the source as a library in Android Studio.

I've searched the web but couldn't find anything. Everywhere is said to import but it is not showing import option in my Android Studio.

Comment: I guess these line should be put in your `gradle.build` file in the `dependecies` section.

Comment: After putting compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0' into your build.gradle  file under dependencies, it will not work immediately, you will have to restart Android Studio first!

Comment: For more info can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059576/import-android-volley-to-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You have to put them in `build.gradle` in `app` module:

[image: build.gradle app module]

Answer (score 0):

remove "" from 1st line
try this
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'